# How is `UUID` generated in Java?

Tags: java, uuid

I understand how `UUIDs` are pretty much unique if they are created using enough entropy. I read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) and trying to understand how they are generated ([RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)).

- How the generation algorithm works?
- What the different 5 groups (`time_low`, `time_mid`, `time_hi_and_version`, `clock_seq_hi_and_res clock_seq_low`, `node`) stand for? (answered [here](http://UUID%20format:%208-4-4-4-12%20-%20Why?))

Edit:
I don't think this is a duplicate of [this](http://UUID%20format:%208-4-4-4-12%20-%20Why?) because I am not asking only the format but also how it is implemented and how the UUID is calculated in Java.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of `UUID format: 8-4-4-4-12 - Why?` because I am not asking only what the format stands for but also how the Java implementation works.

Comment: The Java implementation is open source. You can look it up yourself. Those "5 groups" are documented in the RFC and are not specific the Java.

Comment: With the "go read the implementation by yourself" attitude half of the stack overflow questions should be closed. Even the question this was marked duplicate of should be closed because "It is in the RFC, go to read that".

Comment: Yes, I agree. They should. SO is not a replacement for documentation. If you have a specific question about the details of the implementation, that may be appropriate.

Comment: You seem to be unaware that UUIDs come in different versions. Only one version is based on random number requiring sufficient entropy. The other versions are not. Please read basic documentation such as  [the Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) before posting.

Comment: If this question was not closed as a duplicate, it would be closed as "Too Broad", since you are asking someone to explain how Java implements an entire algorithm.